# .NET read roles from comma separated string instead of from array

Tags: .net, authentication, jwt, openid-connect, claims-authentication

In my JWT I have a list of roles like this: {..., role: "1,2,3", ...}. When my request hits [Authorize(Role = "1")], it returns unauthorized.

Is there a way to parse this comma separated string into an array of roles on my AddAuthentication or AddJwtBearer calls?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this mapping:

```
options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(JwtClaimTypes.Role, JwtClaimTypes.Role);
```

instead of

```
options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey(JwtClaimTypes.Role, JwtClaimTypes.Role);
```

I did write a lengthy post about these problems in a blog post here:
[Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)